# Gtk2 Get data from 2 entries with the same button

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3, gtk2

So, I'm new to gtk and I'm trying to make a login form and I need username and password to be send both when button "Submit" is pressed. How can I do this?
My code:

```
const void button_clicked (GtkWidget *widget,gpointer data)
{
    const gchar* text;
    text = gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(data));
    write(lala,text,100);
}
GtkWidget*window,*label_username,*label_password,*layout,*entry_username,*entry_password,*submit_button;
entry_username = gtk_entry_new();
entry_password = gtk_entry_new();
submit_button = gtk_button_new_with_label("Sumbit");
g_signal_connect(submit_button,"clicked",G_CALLBACK(button_clicked),entry_username;
```

How can I make the submit_button function to recive text from entry_username and entry_password? Thanks!

Comment: You can make a struct with pointers to those entries and pass a pointer to this struct as `data`

Comment: If you're new to GTK+, don't use GTK+ 2 which is very old now. GTK+ 3 has been released in 2011 and is the current stable. GTK+ 4 will probably be released in 2019.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In gtk for situations like this it would be best to pass a structure which contains the widget's as members to the callback function...

```
typedef struct MainWindow 
{

GtkWidget *entry_username, *entry_password;

}MAINWINDOW;

int main(
MAINWINDOW *mainwindow = malloc(sizeof(MAINWINDOW));

mainwindow->entry_username = gtk_entry_new();
mainwindow->entry_password = gtk_entry_new();


g_signal_connect(submit_button,"clicked",G_CALLBACK(button_clicked),mainwindow);
}

const void button_clicked (GtkWidget *widget,gpointer data)
{
    MAINWINDOW *mainwindow = data;
    //now you have both the widget's 
        // modify em as per your wish :)
}
```

this is a very rough example. but something like this should work for your case.